# How to replace a word based on its length?

Tags: java

All words having the given length `wordLength` in the string `sentence` must be replaced with the word `myWord`. All parameters come from user input and may vary. I have tried this way but it only returns the initial string with the initial words.

Here is my source code:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sentence = "";
    int wordLength = 0;
    String myWord = "";
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(is);

    System.out.println("Text input: ");
    sentence = bis.readLine();
    System.out.println("Word lenth to replace");
    wordLength = Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());
    System.out.println("Word to replace to");
    myWord = bis.readLine();

    Text myText = new Text(myWord, sentence, wordLength);
    myText.changeSentence();
    System.out.println("New string" + myText.getSentence());
  }
}

class Text {

  private String mySentence;
  private int charNumber;
  private String wordToChange;
  private String newSentence = "1.";

  public Text(String wordToChange, String mySentece, int charNumber) {
    this.mySentence = mySentece;
    this.wordToChange = wordToChange;
    this.charNumber = charNumber;
  }

  public String getSentence() {
    return newSentence;
  }

  public void changeSentence() {
    int firstPos = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < mySentence.length(); i++) {
      if (mySentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        if (i - firstPos == charNumber) {
          newSentence = newSentence.concat(wordToChange + " ");
          firstPos = i + 1;
        } else {
          newSentence = newSentence.concat(mySentence.substring(firstPos, i + 1));
          firstPos = i + 1;
        }
      } else if (i == mySentence.length() - 1) {
        if (i - firstPos == charNumber) {
          newSentence = newSentence.concat(wordToChange + " ");
          firstPos = i + 1;
        } else {
          newSentence = newSentence.concat(mySentence.substring(firstPos, i + 1));
          firstPos = i + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ```All words of the input length must be replaced by a input word```. Please explain with sample input and output

Comment: @Umeshwaran I mean that first i must input the length of the desired word to be replaced then input a new word to replace.

Comment: Can you share an example of some input and expected output?

Comment: @Kamil      Text input: any  text.
                  Word lenth to replace: 3.
                  Word to replace to: some.
Output: some text  . Something like this

Comment: @Liviu-AdrianMelinte why would you need a "word length" if you could replace it with another word directly?

Comment: @DarkMode: any word in the input that is exactly as long as the *word length* should be replaced with an instance of the *new word*. Both *word length* and *new word* should be specified (input) by the user.

Comment: @DarkMode Because this is the task i received .

Comment: @Liviu-AdrianMelinte: you already seem to have code that looks like it's on the right track. Is there any specific problem with it? Any exceptions you get or some specific input that doesn't produce the expected output?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer My code just returned the initial text. But all in all the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "";
        int wordLenght = 0;
        String myWord = "";
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(is);
        try {
            System.out.println("Text input: ");
            sentence = bis.readLine();
            System.out.println("Word lenth to replace");
            wordLenght = Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());
            System.out.println("Word to replace to");
            myWord = bis.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Text myText = new Text(myWord, sentence, wordLenght);
        System.out.println(myText.getChangeSentence());
    }
}

class Text {
    private String mySentence;
    private int charNumber;
    private String wordToChange;
    private String newSentence = "1.";

    public Text(String wordToChange, String mySentece, int charNumber) {
        this.mySentence = mySentece;
        this.wordToChange = wordToChange;
        this.charNumber = charNumber;
    }

    public String getChangeSentence() {
        String[] words = mySentence.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
            if(words[i].length() == charNumber) {
                words[i] = wordToChange;
            }
        }
        for (String word : words) {
            newSentence += word + " ";
        }
        return newSentence;
    }
}
```

Input : This is a test
word length : 2
word to replace : ii

output: This ii a test

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the only separator of words that is currently considered to appear in the input text is a single white space `" "`. If that's true, then the `changeSentence` method can be quite short. There is no need to do parse the sentence character by characted. Having in mind that the white space is a separator, you can simply split the sentence by the characted `" "` and collect them as words. After that you can just iterate through words and replace ones that lenght matches given input characters number. After that, you can just join words together with the previously used separator and that's it.

Examples if you want to try with loops

```
public void changeSentence() {
    final String[] words = mySentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() == charNumber) {
            words[i] = wordToChange;
        }
    }
    newSentence = String.join(" ", words);
}
```

or with regular expressions

```
public void changeSentence() {
    String regex = "\\b\\w{" + charNumber+ "}\\b";
    newSentence = mySentence.replaceAll(regex, wordToChange);
}
```

or with the stream API

```
public void changeSentence() {
    newSentence = Arrays.stream(mySentence.split(" "))
                .map(s -> s.length() == charNumber ? wordToChange : s)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```